# Authenticate with Azure Active Directory Integration in AWS hosted Application

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory

I want to access a URL ( lets say url1 = http://url1 ) when user will visit this url it will ask for Active Directory Authentication (currently Active Directory will be running on Microsoft Azure ), user will input Active Directory Credentials, and after user get authenticated , System should redirect to Web URL2 ( lets say url2 = http://url2 ) an Angular 2 + ROR Web application running on AWS.

I tried this [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-amazon-web-service-tutorial/) to setup, it is working fine but after the authentication it is redirecting to AWS Console but I want to redirect to my application Hosted on AWS.

Anybody has idea how I can do it?

Comment: as far as azure active directory goes you cannot send credentials and send it and authenticate. it is also not a good practice. for now only native apps are allowed . if not already please check the options available in AAD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios

Comment: basically the problem is we have web application already hosted in AWS , now client have one more company and want to give access the user who are already in Azure Active directory and want same users to be authenticated rather than creating new users in AWS to use Single Sing-On, so we have to find a way to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this application in AAD:
https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/aad.aws

Make sure to follow the instructions on this tutorial correctly(i.e. pay attention to Custom Claims):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-amazon-web-service-tutorial

Note: You can Enter your application Identifier as urn:name1:name2, on the AAD Single Sign on steps.

For the AWS side(besides what the tutorial above says) you need to leverage the NodeJS sdk AssumeRolewithSaml STS(Security Token Service) call on your application, more details here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html